# How to enable scrolling for dynamically created tabs within tabbedpanel widget in kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

My kivy app contains a main screen and 10 more screens. Mainscreen has a tabbed panel widget with 5 tabs. Each tab represents a group and each group has two buttons that represent two screens. on button press event the corresponding screen will be loaded.

There are no errors in my code. However, only few tabs gets displayed in the tabbed panel. kindly suggest how do I create scrollable tabs within the tabbed panel widget. I referred to the documentation and came acrross switch_to function but there is no illustration how to use it.

tst.py

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.tabbedpanel import TabbedPanelItem
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class windowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass

class MainScreen(Screen):
    mytabs = ObjectProperty(None)
    category = {'Group 1':['Screen 1', 'Screen 2'],
                'Group 2': ['Screen 3', 'Screen 4'],
                'Group 3': ['Screen 5', 'Screen 6'],
                'Group 4': ['Screen 7', 'Screen 8'],
                'Group 5': ['Screen 9', 'Screen 10']
                }

    tabs = []
    buttons = []

    def add_tabs(self):
        for item in self.category:
            self.tabs.append(TabbedPanelItem(text = item))
            button_grid = BoxLayout(orientation = 'vertical')   
            for value in self.category[item]:
                self.buttons.append(Button(text = value))
                button_grid.add_widget(self.buttons[-1])
            self.tabs[-1].add_widget(button_grid)
            self.mytabs.add_widget(self.tabs[-1])
        for i in self.buttons:
            i.bind(on_press = self.navigate)

    def navigate(self,instance):
        self.manager.current = instance.text

class Screen1(Screen):    
    pass

class Screen2(Screen):    
    pass

class Screen3(Screen):    
    pass

class Screen4(Screen):    
    pass

class Screen5(Screen):    
    pass

class Screen6(Screen):    
    pass

class Screen7(Screen):    
    pass

class Screen8(Screen):    
    pass

class Screen9(Screen):    
    pass

class Screen10(Screen):    
    pass

class Docky(App):                
    def build(self):    
        return windowManager()            

if __name__=="__main__":
    Docky().run()
```

Docky.kv

```
# File: docapp.py

<WindowManager>:
    MainScreen:
    Screen1:
    Screen2:
    Screen3:
    Screen4:
    Screen5:
    Screen6:
    Screen7:
    Screen8:
    Screen9:
    Screen10:

<MainScreen>:
    name: 'main'
    mytabs: my_tabs


    TabbedPanel:
        id: my_tabs
        tab_pos: 'left_top'
        tab_width: 150
        size_hint: 1, 1
        do_default_tab: False
        on_kv_post:
            root.add_tabs()



<Screen1>:
    name: 'Screen 1'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'this is screen 1'
            #size_hint: None, 0.8
        Button: 
            text: 'Back to main screen'
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            on_press: app.root.current = 'main'


<Screen2>:
    name: 'Screen 2'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'this is screen 2'
        Button: 
            text: 'Back to main screen'
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            on_press: app.root.current = 'main'

<Screen3>:
    name: 'Screen 3'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'this is screen 3'
            #size_hint: None, 0.8
        Button: 
            text: 'Back to main screen'
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            on_press: app.root.current = 'main'


<Screen4>:
    name: 'Screen 4'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'this is screen 4'
        Button: 
            text: 'Back to main screen'
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            on_press: app.root.current = 'main'

<Screen5>:
    name: 'Screen 5'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'this is screen 5'
            #size_hint: None, 0.8
        Button: 
            text: 'Back to main screen'
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            on_press: app.root.current = 'main'


<Screen6>:
    name: 'Screen 6'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'this is screen 6'
        Button: 
            text: 'Back to main screen'
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            on_press: app.root.current = 'main'

<Screen7>:
    name: 'Screen 7'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'this is screen 7'
            #size_hint: None, 0.8
        Button: 
            text: 'Back to main screen'
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            on_press: app.root.current = 'main'


<Screen8>:
    name: 'Screen 8'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'this is screen 8'
        Button: 
            text: 'Back to main screen'
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            on_press: app.root.current = 'main'

<Screen9>:
    name: 'Screen 9'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'this is screen 9'
            #size_hint: None, 0.8
        Button: 
            text: 'Back to main screen'
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            on_press: app.root.current = 'main'


<Screen10>:
    name: 'Screen 10'
    BoxLayout:
        orientation: 'vertical'
        Label:
            text: 'this is screen 10'
        Button: 
            text: 'Back to main screen'
            size_hint: 1, 0.2
            on_press: app.root.current = 'main'
```

Comment: The tabs in a `TabbedPanel` are scrollable by default.

Comment: Please run my code and check..I added two more screens just to be sure..but again the same issue..I am unable to scroll tabs

Comment: I ran your code exactly as posted, and the tabs are scrollable. I am running Python 3.6.9 and Kivy 1.11.1 on Ubuntu 18.04. What are you using?